# How can I convert from cborHex to VRFKeyHash type from the Cardano Serialization Lib?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-serialization-lib, hash, signing-key-file

I need to generate a VRF Key Hash in this format: `vrf_vk13hg4gg5fg67399nuz2ldk89kqw9h379cfgtkpvd83ra89f908kcqv2cw3j`

When I generate it using `cardano-cli`, I get this file:

```
{
    "type": "VrfVerificationKey_PraosVRF",
    "description": "VRF Verification Key",
    "cborHex": "5820d3e6e69edf63e50ce0d12bc8fd891d6d00a09cb484a55f99caf0767bd9d75488"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert this to `VRFKeyHash`. I'm using this function (I'm reading the value directly from the file, that's why I'm parsing it):

```
const fromHex=(hex)=>Buffer.from(hex,"hex");
const vrfKeyHash = CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_bytes(fromHex(JSON.parse(vrfKeyFile).cborHex));
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Deserialization failed in VRFKeyHash because: Invalid cbor: expected tuple 'hash length' of length 32 but got length Len(34).
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from `cborHex` to `VRFKeyHash` I did the following, assuming there's a file with this format...

```
{
    "type": "VrfVerificationKey_PraosVRF",
    "description": "VRF Verification Key",
    "cborHex": "5820d3e6e69edf63e50ce0d12bc8fd891d6d00a09cb484a55f99caf0767bd9d75488"
}
```

...which can be generated using `cardano-cli` or `cardanocli-js`:

```
const vrfKeyFile = readFileSync(vrfKeyAccount.vkey, 'utf-8');
CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_bytes(Buffer.from(JSON.parse(vrfKeyFile).cborHex.substring(4), "hex"));
```

You need to get rid of the first 2 bytes ("`5820`" prefix) in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Verification keys can be represented in different ways. The one that you want is a representation where the key hash is converted with a prefix `vrf_` to the bech32 format. This can be done via the following repo [(1)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/bech32).
Given your specific given vrf verification key file you first have to convert it to a vrf key hash. This can be done via the cardano-cli with

```
cardano-cli node key-hash-VRF --verification-key-file fileName.vkey
```

Which returns `80bdf88001bcfb0723f93aff337b299d1502f1d1884afe65342b7b8dfd18c2e6` for your vkey file. Then one can convert this hash to bech32 format with prefix `vrf_` as follows

```
cabal run exe:bech32 -- vrf_ <<< 80bdf88001bcfb0723f93aff337b299d1502f1d1884afe65342b7b8dfd18c2e6
```

which returns `vrf_1sz7l3qqphnaswgle8tlnx7efn52s9uw33p90uef59dacmlgcctnqut3ndw`.
To reverse the bech32 transformation you can run the following

```
cabal run exe:bech32 -- <<< vrf_vk13hg4gg5fg67399nuz2ldk89kqw9h379cfgtkpvd83ra89f908kcqv2cw3j
```

which return `8dd154228946bd12967c12bedb1cb6038b78f8b84a1760b1a788fa72a4af3db0`, the vrf key hash of the example bech32 address you gave.

Comment: Do you know what conversion should I apply to cborHex in order to work with Cardano Serialization Lib?

const vrfKeyHash = CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_bytes(X)

Imagine that X is the cborHex. If I provide it directly that way, I get the following:

"JsValue("Deserialization failed in VRFKeyHash because: Invalid cbor: expected tuple 'hash length' of length 32 but got length Len(34).")"

I have also tried converting it to bytes, but same error.

Comment: Note that in the bech32 is something similar to JSON, to indicate if something is a bytestring or a list etc some bytes indicate those objects. If you have a look at cbor.me and put in the full you will see the key is `D3E6E69EDF63E50CE0D12BC8FD891D6D00A09CB484A55F99CAF0767BD9D75488`. Which has length 32 not 34. I am no expert on the serialization lib so I cannot help with that unfortunately.

Comment: Also see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dcspark/cip5-js, this might help.

Comment: Thank you very much!